# OpenCL kernel not vectorized

Tags: opencl, vectorization

I am trying to build a kernel to do parallel string search. To this end I tend to use a finite state machine. The transition table of the fsm is in the kernel argument states. The code:

```
 __kernel void Find ( __constant char *text,
        const      int offset,
        const      int tlenght,
        __constant char *characters,
        const int clength,
        const int maxlength,
        __constant int *states,
        const int statesdim){

    private char c;
    private int state;
    private const int id = get_global_id(0);

    if (id<(tlenght-maxlength)) {

        private int cIndex,sd,s,k;

        for (int i=0; i<maxlength; i++) {

            c = text[i+offset];

            cIndex = -1;

            for (int j=0; j<clength; j++) {

                if (characters[j]==c) {
                    cIndex = j;
                }       
            }    

            if (cIndex==-1) {

                state = 0;
                break;

            }  else {

                s = states[state+cIndex*statesdim];

            }

            if (state<=0) break;

        }    
    }
}
```

If I compile this kernel using iocgui, I get the result:

```
Using default instruction set architecture.
Intel OpenCL CPU device was found!
Device name: Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU       T4400  @ 2.20GHz
Device version: OpenCL 1.1 (Build 31360.31426)
Device vendor: Intel(R) Corporation
Device profile: FULL_PROFILE
Build started
Kernel <Find> was successfully vectorized
Done.
Build succeeded!
```

When I change the line where the new state is determined to:

```
state = states[state+cIndex*statesdim];
```

The result is:

```
Using default instruction set architecture.
Intel OpenCL CPU device was found!
Device name: Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU       T4400  @ 2.20GHz
Device version: OpenCL 1.1 (Build 31360.31426)
Device vendor: Intel(R) Corporation
Device profile: FULL_PROFILE
Build started
Kernel <Find> was not vectorized
Done.
Build succeeded!
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
X = states[state+cIndex*statesdim];
```

cannot be vectorized since the index is not necessarily evaluates to accesses to consequent bytes across threads.

Notice that in your first kernel, you have the destination variable `s` where it has not written back to global memory. Therefore, compiler may optimize the code and remove the `s = states[state+cIndex*statesdim];` statement. Therefore, it looks your statement has been vectorized but it is not so.